# Java : prune method for Java linkedlist

Tags: java

I am independently studying CS251 from Vanderbilt University. The work is to write a facade wrapper for character array and make it re-sizeable. However, there is a a method **prune()** and I don't understand what it is supposed to do. Can you guys shed some light on what might this method mean? Since, I don't go to that school, I can't ask anybody.

https://github.com/iamparas/CS251/blob/master/assignments/assignment1/ugrad/src/vandy/cs251/CharList.java

Here, is a node for that Java code.

```
private class Node {
    /**
     * Value stored in the Node.
     */
// TODO - you fill in here

    /**
     * Reference to the next node in the list.
     */
// TODO - you fill in here

    /**
     * Default constructor (no op).
     */
    Node() {
    }

    /**
     * Construct a Node from a @a prev Node.
     */
    Node(Node prev) {
        // TODO - you fill in here
    }

    /**
     * Construct a Node from a @a value and a @a prev Node.
     */
    Node(char value, Node prev) {
        // TODO - you fill in here
    }

    /**
     * Ensure all subsequent nodes are properly deallocated.
     */
    void prune() {
        // TODO - you fill in here
        // Leaving the list fully linked could *potentially* cause
        // a pathological performance issue for the garbage
        // collector.
    }
```

Comment: Is this simply "de-referencing" each node in the list from the one it's linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I provide is simplified but I hope conceptually explains what you need. In Java, Objects are kept on the heap. When garbage collection takes places, Objects that are no longer referenced directly or indirectly by a garbage collection root are removed from the heap.

If an Object is still referenced by a garbage collection root, it will not be garbage collected. All the prune method needs to do is set prev and next values for each node after the current node to null. This will allow the garbage collector to remove these Objects from the heap.

Comment: *If an Object is still referenced by another Object, it will not be garbage collected*: this is not simplification. It's just wrong.

Comment: Updated, is that better? My intention was to avoid going into too much detail about GC and just highlight the need for dereferencing. Give me a shout, if it's still factually incorrect, I'll remove it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well, it's not as incorrect anymore, but it still implies that setting the prev and next nodes to null is necessary for the objects to be GCed. The fact is that it's not necessary at all. By the way, Java has a standard LinkedList method, which is a bidirectional linled list of nodes, and it doesn't have any prune() method. Setting the refs to null *might help* the GC, but it surely isn't necessary.

Comment: I thought the same thing, in my mind the exercise is flawed but from reading the areas the tutor wants filled in, this is what Paris needs to do for the assignment.